# Writing an readin json file i have this error: Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am trying to dynamically create json file on device, the file is created successfully, but when I try to do the jsonDecode it throws this error.

The error is this:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following LateError was thrown building Home(dirty, state: HomeState#853db):
LateInitializationError: Field 'fileContent' has not been initialized.

The relevant error-causing widget was
Home
package:json_storage/main.dart:101
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      HomeState.fileContent (package:json_storage/main.dart)
package:json_storage/main.dart:1
#1      HomeState.build
package:json_storage/main.dart:183
#2      StatefulElement.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4691
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4574
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4746
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (23568): true
E/flutter (23568): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)
E/flutter (23568):
E/flutter (23568): ^
E/flutter (23568):
E/flutter (23568): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1404:5)
E/flutter (23568): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.close (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:522:7)
E/flutter (23568): #2      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:41:10)
E/flutter (23568): #3      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:506:36)
E/flutter (23568): #4      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:157:41)
E/flutter (23568): #5      jsonDecode (dart:convert/json.dart:96:10)
E/flutter (23568): #6      HomeState.initState.<anonymous closure>
package:json_storage/main.dart:131
E/flutter (23568): #7      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)
E/flutter (23568): #8      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
E/flutter (23568): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (23568):
```

I have already tried putting it async just in case but it seems that it is not the problem, so I do not know what may be happening.

Here I leave the code, it is simply the main.dart file I do not have anything else since it is a test app to see if I could create that json and write in it, also I have used the path_provider package, but that's all, I can put a repository in github if necessary, but just copy and paste this code and add path_provider in pubspec.yaml.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new Home(),
  ));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  TextEditingController keyInputController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController valueInputController = new TextEditingController();

  late File jsonFile;
  late Directory dir;
  String fileName = 'myJsonFile.json';
  bool fileExists = false;
  // Si usas otra cosa Pon String, dynamic
  late Map<String, dynamic> fileContent;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((Directory directory) {
      dir = directory;
      jsonFile = new File(dir.path + '/' + fileName);
      jsonFile.createSync();
      fileExists = jsonFile.existsSync();
      print(fileExists);
      if (fileExists) {
        fileContent = jsonDecode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync());
        setState(() {});
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    keyInputController.dispose();
    valueInputController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void createFile(Map<String, String> content, Directory dir, String fileName) {
    print('Creating file!');
    File file = new File(dir.path + '/' + fileName);
    file.createSync();
    fileExists = true;
    file.writeAsStringSync(json.encode(content));
  }

  void writeToFile(String key, String value) {
    print('Writing to file');
    Map<String, String> content = {key: value};
    if (fileExists) {
      print('File exists');
      Map<String, String> jsonFileContent =
          json.decode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync());
      jsonFileContent.addAll(content);
      jsonFile.writeAsStringSync(json.encode(jsonFileContent));
    } else {
      print('File does not exists!');
      createFile(content, dir, fileName);
    }
    this.setState(() {
      fileContent = json.decode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync());
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("JSON Tutorial"),
      ),
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0)),
          new Text(
            "File content: ",
            style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          new Text((fileContent.toString() == '')
              ? 'PlaceHolder'
              : fileContent.toString()),
          new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0)),
          new Text("Add to JSON file: "),
          new TextField(
            controller: keyInputController,
          ),
          new TextField(
            controller: valueInputController,
          ),
          new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0)),
          new ElevatedButton(
              child: new Text("Add key, value pair"),
              onPressed: () {
                writeToFile(keyInputController.text, valueInputController.text);
              })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any idea what can happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I already found my fault, the main problem is that this code was with the Dart 1 version and when trying to adapt it to Dart 2 I found the problem.
What happened is that when creating the json file it is empty so as it does not have any key, value, it seems that a `Map<String, dynamic>` is generated, since in one of the tests I was doing it gave me this error :

```
The following _TypeError was thrown building Home(dirty, state: HomeState # 5f124):
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>' of 'function result'
```

So I decided to change my fileContent from this:

```
late Map<String, String> fileContent;
```

to this:

```
late Map fileContent;
```

Then I decided to change all the logic to leave it like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new Home(),
  ));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  TextEditingController keyInputController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController valueInputController = new TextEditingController();
  late File jsonFile;
  late Directory directory;
  bool fileExists = false;
  late Map fileContent;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((dir) async {
      directory = dir;
      jsonFile = File('${directory.path}/juegos.json');
      await jsonFile.create();
      fileExists = await jsonFile.exists();
      print(fileExists);
      if (fileExists) {
        if (await jsonFile.readAsString() == '') {
          fileContent = {};
        } else {
          fileContent = jsonDecode(await jsonFile.readAsString());
        }
        setState(() {});
      }
    });
  }

  createFile() async {
    jsonFile = File('${directory.path}/juegos.json');
    await jsonFile.create();
  }

  writeToFile(String key, String value) async {
    if (fileExists) {
      if (fileContent.containsKey(key)) {
        fileContent.update(key, (v) => v = value);
      } else {
        fileContent.putIfAbsent(key, () => value);
      }
      jsonFile.writeAsString(jsonEncode(fileContent));
    } else {
      createFile();
    }
    fileContent = jsonDecode(await jsonFile.readAsString());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    keyInputController.dispose();
    valueInputController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("JSON Tutorial"),
      ),
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0)),
          new Text(
            "File content: ",
            style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          new Text((fileExists) ? fileContent.toString() : 'Esta vacio'),
          new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0)),
          new Text("Add to JSON file: "),
          new TextField(
            controller: keyInputController,
          ),
          new TextField(
            controller: valueInputController,
          ),
          new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0)),
          new ElevatedButton(
              child: new Text("Add key, value pair"),
              onPressed: () {
                writeToFile(keyInputController.text, valueInputController.text);
                setState(() {});
              })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Since the file was empty, it was necessary to put a condition of if it was empty that fileContent is equal to an empty map, and not equal to a total empty ...

And in my wirteToFile I simply verify that if fileContent already has the key that I want to write that I update or else add it, finally I update fileContent again.

Either way now fileContent is never empty. that that was the error, since it tried to read something where there was absolutely nothing.

Hope this helps someone and thanks for the help @h8moss in the end he was right and it was because the file was empty, although his change proposal did not help me, the only thing I had to do was verify that it was not empty and if it was, fill it at least with an empty map.
So thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are creating a file

```
dir = directory;
jsonFile = new File(dir.path + '/' + fileName);
jsonFile.createSync();
```

then making sure it was created

```
fileExists = jsonFile.existsSync();
print(fileExists);
if (fileExists) {
  ...
}
```

And then if it was, you are reading its contents and parsing them as JSON

```
fileContent = jsonDecode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync());
setState(() {});
```

So The file you just created is empty, and so you are reading an empty file and passing an empty string into the jsonDecode function. which throws an error

You also declare this function, but never call it:

```
void createFile(Map<String, String> content, Directory dir, String fileName) {
    print('Creating file!');
    File file = new File(dir.path + '/' + fileName);
    file.createSync();
    fileExists = true;
    file.writeAsStringSync(json.encode(content));
  }
```

So I'm guessing what you actually wanted to do was something like this:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((Directory directory) {
      dir = directory;
      createFile(content, dir, fileName);
      print(fileExists);
      if (fileExists) {
        fileContent = jsonDecode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync());
        setState(() {});
      }
    });
  }
```

Also, the createFile method only uses class fields, so you don't need any arguments on it I don't think.

Comment: You are right, but I am using createFile() in the other writeToFile function, so that the file is created if it does not exist, maybe it is a redundancy since the file is created but it is empty as you said, but it is only to assure me a future failure.

I have tried the change you told me but it remains the same.

And you are right that the createFile method only uses class fields, but the function, although it is private there, I want to be able to reuse it in the future, that's why I put the arguments. Thanks for your help, in the end I couldn't fix it, I'll keep trying.

Comment: Also I tried this condition simply to not pass anything empty to jsonDecode ():
```fileContent = jsonDecode (jsonFile.readAsStringSync () == ''? "{'key': 'value'}": jsonFile.readAsStringSync ());```

But it is still the same.

I even tried writing to the file once it was created:

```jsonFile = new File (dir.path + '/' + fileName);
jsonFile.createSync ();
fileExists = jsonFile.existsSync();
writeToFile ('key', 'value');```

But it still does not work, it seems that the fault is in the Decode function.